# How to build django-mptt tree without rebuilding after each insert?

Tags: django, django-mptt, mptt

I'm building large mptt tree.
I'd like to insert all nodes and after that start method for rebuilding whole tree:

```
for i in range(big_loop):
    ...
    m.save() # Saving mptt object. Tree is rebuild.
some_mptt_model.tree.rebuild()
```

How can I avoid rebuilding tree after each insert?

I've found only depracted keyword in `.save` method:

> In earlier versions, MPTTModel.save() had a raw keyword argument. If
>   True, the MPTT fields would not be updated during the save. This
>   (undocumented) argument has now been removed.

Comment: I don't think so, at least as far as MPTT goes you should rebuild part of the tree index on the right side of inserted item after every insert. With MPTT reads are very cheap while updates are very expensive. Although rather then looping over right hand items you could just update their index +2 in one go.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable rebuilding tree after each insert using [disable_mptt_updates](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/mptt.managers.html#mptt.managers.TreeManager.disable_mptt_updates) method:

```
with MyModel.objects.disable_mptt_updates():
    # some bulk updates...
    for obj in objects:
        obj.save()

# And then you can rebuild the tree.
MyModel.objects.rebuild()
```

Comment: Looks good but I'm no longer working on this and I can't try it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be solved with a help of [Proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). In proxy model, `save` method could be overriden to call `save`method of `models.Model` instead of MPTT `save` method. Something like this:

```
class MyNonMPTTModel(MyMPTTModel):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(models.Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I did not try this code, but I guess it could work.